# 'Port' object has no attribute 'socket'

Tags: python, ssh, twisted

I'm using twisted python to make a simple SSH server on a custom port. I create a Port object with `port = reactor.listenTCP(_port, sshfactory)`, where _port is a variable that holds the integer of the port. I free up the port when shutting down the server with the commands `port.loseConnection()` and `port.connectionLost(reason=None)`. If I attempt to start the server, stop it, and start it again, I get the titular error 'Port' object has no attribute 'socket'

Edit: full error message:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1175, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 779, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 238, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 307, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 323, in _runCallbacks
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 736, in <lambda>
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: callable(*args, **kw))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 981, in connectionLost
    self._closeSocket()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 92, in _closeSocket
    skt = self.socket
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Port' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

Edit2: stopListening code sample (Python 2.7):

stopListening sample.py

```
from twisted.cred import portal, checkers, credentials
from twisted.conch import error, avatar, recvline, interfaces as conchinterfaces
from twisted.conch.ssh import factory, userauth, connection, keys, session, common
from twisted.conch.insults import insults
from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from zope.interface import implements
import threading
import os

class SSHDemoProtocol(recvline.HistoricRecvLine):
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def connectionMade(self):
        recvline.HistoricRecvLine.connectionMade(self)
        self.showPrompt()

    def showPrompt(self):
        self.terminal.write("$ ")

class SSHDemoRealm:
    implements(portal.IRealm)
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if conchinterfaces.IConchUser in interfaces:
            return interfaces[0], SSHDemoAvatar(avatarId), lambda: None
        else:
            raise Exception("No supported interfaces found.")

def getRSAKeys():
    if not (os.path.exists('public.key') and os.path.exists('private.key')):
        # generate a RSA keypair
        print("Generating RSA keypair...")
        from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
        KEY_LENGTH = 1024
        rsaKey = RSA.generate(KEY_LENGTH, common.entropy.get_bytes)
        publicKeyString = keys.makePublicKeyString(rsaKey)
        privateKeyString = keys.makePrivateKeyString(rsaKey)
        # save keys for next time
        file('public.key', 'w+b').write(publicKeyString)
        file('private.key', 'w+b').write(privateKeyString)
        print("done.")
    else:
        publicKeyString = file('public.key').read()
        privateKeyString = file('private.key').read()
    return publicKeyString, privateKeyString

def launchServer():
    _port = 4564
    password = 'password'
    sshFactory = factory.SSHFactory()
    sshFactory.portal = portal.Portal(SSHDemoRealm())
    users = {'user': password}
    sshFactory.portal.registerChecker(
        checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(**users))
    pubKeyString, privKeyString = getRSAKeys()
    sshFactory.publicKeys = {
        'ssh-rsa': keys.getPublicKeyString(data=pubKeyString)}
    sshFactory.privateKeys = {
        'ssh-rsa': keys.getPrivateKeyObject(data=privKeyString)}
    global port
    port = reactor.listenTCP(_port, sshFactory)
    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', stopServer)
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)

def startServer():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=launchServer)
    thread.start()

def stopServer():
    global port
    port.stopListening()
    reactor.stop()
    reactor.crash()

startServer()
stopServer()
startServer()
```

traceback:

```
>>> Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/paul/Desktop/Down2Home/stopListening sample.py", line 62, in launchServer
    port = reactor.listenTCP(_port, sshFactory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-9.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 355, in listenTCP
    p.startListening()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-9.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 855, in startListening
    raise CannotListenError, (self.interface, self.port, le)
CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:4564: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

Comment: Perhaps I should note that I am using Twisted 9.0 because that's what I had to do to make it compatible with an older code example I was working from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be ditching the threads entirely, and using a built-in method of interfacing with a GUI. `tksupport.install(root)` Twisted is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

[`listenTCP`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html#listenTCP) returns an [`IListeningPort`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html); `IListeningPort` does not have `loseConnection` or `connectionLost` methods.  Instead, it has [`stopListening`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html#stopListening).  The presence of those methods that you're calling is an unfortunate accident.  You should try using the publicly advertised interfaces and see if that works.

(Also, you should post a [completely runnable bit of code](http://sscce.org), so that we actually know what you mean by "stop it and start it again", as well as a complete traceback, rather than just a snippet of an error message.)

Additionally, Twisted APIs may not be invoked from arbitrary threads.  This code will provoke undefined and difficult to predict behavior from Twisted:

```
def stopServer():
    global port
    port.stopListening()
    reactor.stop()
    reactor.crash()
```

for several reasons.  First, `startServer` set up the application and started the reactor in another thread.  This means `port.stopListening()` is not allowed because it's a Twisted API being called in the wrong thread.  Second, `reactor.crash()` is really only a testing helper, and even in that area, its use is strongly discouraged as better testing techniques have been developed since `reactor.crash()` was invented.

You might get away with something like this to fix these problems:

```
from twisted.internet.threads import blockingCallFromThread

def startServer():
    global thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=launchServer)
    thread.start()

def stopServer():
    global port, thread
    blockingCallFromThread(reactor, port.stopListening)
    reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)
    thread.join()
    thread = None
```

Of course, the use of globals isn't ideal, but I'm sticking with them here to keep the code close to your original.

What this does is:

- Call port.stopListening in the reactor thread using `blockingCallFromThread`.  Additionally, this will block until the `Deferred` returned by `stopListening` fires.  This means that when that line is done, the port will no longer be in use.
- Call reactor.stop in the reactor thread using `reactor.callFromThread`.  Since this call is intended to stop the reactor, I don't think it's safe to use `blockingCallFromThread` since once the reactor stops the inter-thread communication mechanism may no longer work.  Also, `reactor.stop` doesn't return a `Deferred` so there's nothing useful to block on anyway.
- Wait for the reactor to stop running by joining the thread in which it is running (which will block until `launchServer` returns, which it will do as soon as `reactor.run()` returns, which it will once the reactor stops).

However, you may also want to consider not using threads at all in this way.  There's no particular reason to do so, at least none I can determine from this minimal example.  If you have some other use of threads that seems necessary to you, that might make good fodder for another SO question. :)

Comment: I figured my code was a bit too long and messy. Stop it and start it again basically means run the two methods I was using to close the port, and run the methods to listen on the port.

Comment: Just tried stopListening(). I think I used this before and abandoned it because it doesn't work. When I try to listen again on the port after closing it, it says the address is already in use.

Comment: Please attach a complete code sample that uses `stopListening`, along with a traceback from that code.  Attempting to re-construct based on your description, it works fine for me.

Comment: There you go, it's in the OP.

Comment: `stopListening` returns a `Deferred`.  You can't listen on the port again until after the `Deferred` fires.  Also, after calling `reactor.stop` you cannot call `reactor.run` again (at least, you can't expect it to work again).  And `reactor.crash` is not really for use in any real programs, it's sort of a mistake, sort of a testing help.  Try calling `stopListening`, add a callback that calls `listenTCP` again, and just leave out the `reactor.stop` and `reactor.crash`.

Comment: How long does it take for the Deferred to fire? I've waited over a minute before attempting to restart the server.

Comment: I'm not sure commenting here will bring this page to the top but I hope it does because I'm still not having any luck here.

Comment: "How long does it take for the Deferred to fire?" suggests a misunderstanding of the point of Deferreds.  A Deferred is how you get notified that something has happened.  You don't wait a specified length of time before getting a result out of a Deferred: you add a callback function to a Deferred and the callback function is called as soon as the Deferred has a result.

Comment: I use threads because the server is started and stopped from a GUI.

Comment: The use of the code in the solution causes the GUI to freeze when attempting to stop the server.

Comment: Twisted supports GUIs directly. You don't need to use threads. What GUI library are you using?